# Primefaces: update en elemento p:fileupload causa el cierre de un diálogo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estamos desarrollando una aplicación mediante **Primefaces 5.0** que requiere subir y almacenar ficheros en el servidor. La parte que se encarga de subir el fichero se introduce en un formulario independiente, dentro del diálogo `dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist`. Dicho diálogo, a su vez, es invocado por otro diálogo (`dlgEditarIncidenciaHist`):

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="incidenciaHistForm">
        <!-- Codigo -->

        <p:dialog id="dlgEditarIncidenciaHist" widgetVar="dlgEditarIncidenciaHist"
                  width="1060"
                  style="font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 15px;"
                  modal="true" closable="true"
                  header="Editar incidencia">

        <!-- Codigo -->
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog
            style="font-size: 12px;"
            id="dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist"
            header="Subir fichero de ayuda"
            height="160" width="450"
            widgetVar="dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist"
            modal="true">

        <h:form id="uploadFicheroIncidenciaHistForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload
                    update=":incidenciaHistForm:dlgEditarIncidenciaHist"
                    oncomplete="PF('dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist').hide();"
                    value="#{incidenciaHistControlador.editarIncidenciaHistBean.uploadedFile}"
                    fileUploadListener="#{incidenciaHistControlador.editarIncidenciaHistBean.procesarFichero}"
                    mode="advanced" label="Seleccionar fichero" auto="true"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/">
            </p:fileUpload>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

La tarea de subir y almacenar el fichero se realiza adecuadamente, es decir, **el fichero se ha subido correctamente**. El problema viene dado cuando finaliza la tarea de subir el fichero, pues deberia actualizar el diálogo `dlgEditarIncidenciaHist` tal y como indica el atributo `update` del componente (`update=":incidenciaHistForm:dlgEditarIncidenciaHist"`) y cerrar el diálogo `dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist`. Sin embargo el resultado es que cierra el diálogo `dlgEditarIncidenciaHist`, de hecho, me da la sensación de que refresca la página entera, aunque no estoy del todo seguro.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, había algún problema derivado de usar el mismo valor para id y widgetVar en los p:dialog. Cambia el valor de uno de los dos.

Answer (score 1):

prueba quitando auto="true" de fileUpload. ami me actualiza correctamente los elementos, los cuales tengo dentro de un solo form y sin usar widgetVar solo con id

Comment: He seguido los pasos que indicas, dejando un único formulario, eliminando el `atributo auto="true"` y el `widgetVar`, sin embargo me da el error `FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` por lo que he probado a incluir el atributo `enctype` a la etiqueta `<h:form>`, quedando del siguiente modo: `<h:form id="incidenciaHistForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, sin embargo sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿tienes las configuraciones necesarias en web.xml para subir archivos?

Comment: Si, si el problema no reside en la subida de ficheros en sí. El problema es que cierra el díalogo `dlgSubirFicheroIncidenciaHist` cuando no debería. Pero el fichero si que se ha subido y almacenado.

Answer (score 1):

A veces primefaces es oscuro y esconde horrores, especialmente con los eventos de subida de archivos. Probablemente el back end no está finalizando correctamente la subida del archivo.

Pon tambien `process="@this"` y `update="@this :incidenciaHistForm:dlgEditarIncidenciaHist"`

Answer (score 1):

Aquí el problema no está dado por el componente, ya que ocurre lo mismo con `commandLink`, `commandButton`, etc.. La solución para prevenir que el diálogo se te cierre se basa en `process="@this"`. De hecho no es necesario utilizar `@this` en el método `update` y puedes tranquilamente actualizar el componente que necesites.

Les comparto un ejemplo con ***CommandLink***.

```
<p:commandLink
    value="Volver"
    actionListener="#{gestionArchivosBancoBean.actionPreparaDialogoVincular}"
    update=":formDialogoVincularRegistro:outputDialogoVincularRegistros"
>    
    <p:ajax process="@this"></p:ajax>
</p:commandLink>
```

Este código se encuentra dentro de un diálogo, junto con un par de `DataTables` y demás componentes.

Aquí más ejemplos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0vXU2QV7GWU3PmN_vHcSNw